# Cloud Firestore error while trying to retrieve List

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I started working with Cloud Firestore in a personal project and have been facing an issue trying to retrieve a List from a Document while I still managed to receive some data from the backend, it's not that precise while checking the DB.

```
Collection
 DocumentN
     -otherStuff
     -usermatches:                <---- This is an array  
          (0): 
             -Score:0
             -Id:123 
          (1): 
             -Score:1
             -Id:456
```

**Schema**

[image: Firestore]

I've been trying alot and the class below is me solving momentarily the **Error** `HashMap cannot be cast to parameter..` but I do not know how to really achieve what i need, if you have any feed back or have any recommendations pls tell me

**Backend.kt**

```
docRef = db.collection("userdata").document(user.user_id)
                docRef.get()
                        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                            if (task.isSuccessful) {

                                val document: DocumentSnapshot = task.result

                                val cedula = document.data!!["cedula"] as Long
                                val points = document.data!!["points"] as Long
 //                                    val usermatches = document.data!!["usermatches"] as HashMap<String, Any>
                                val alias = document.data!!["username"] as String

//                                     val usermatches = document.toObject(Usermatches::class.java)

                                val map: MutableMap<String, Any>? = document.data
                                for (entry in map!!.entries) {
                                    if (entry.key == "usermatches") {

                                        val list = entry.value as ArrayList<Any>

                                        for (each in list){

                                            for (entry2 in  each as HashMap<String, Any>){

                                                var home_score: Long = 0
                                                var winner: Long = 0
                                                var userchanged: Boolean = true
                                                var id: String = ""
                                                var away_score: Long = 0

                                                val usermatch = Usermatches(home_score, away_score, id, userchanged, winner)

                                                when {
                                                    entry2.key == "away_score" -> {
                                                        away_score = entry2.value as Long

                                                        usermatch.away_score = away_score
//                                                            println(away_score)
                                                    }
                                                    entry2.key == "home_score" -> {

                                                        home_score = entry2.value as Long
                                                        usermatch.home_score = home_score
//                                                            println(home_score)
                                                    }
                                                    entry2.key == "id" -> {
                                                        id = entry2.value as String
                                                        usermatch.id = id
//                                                            println(id)
                                                    }
                                                    entry2.key == "userchanged" -> {
                                                        userchanged = entry2.value as Boolean
                                                        usermatch.userchanged = userchanged
//                                                            println(userchanged)
                                                    }
                                                    entry2.key == "winner" -> {
                                                        winner = entry2.value as Long
                                                        usermatch.winner = winner
//                                                            println(winner)
                                                    }

                                                }
                                                mDisposable.add(usermatchesViewModel.insert(Usermatches(home_score, away_score, id, userchanged, winner))
                                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                                    .subscribe{ println("Checking")})

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting Usermatches ", task.exception)
                            }

                        }
            })
```

**Usermatches Data Class**

```
@Entity
data class Usermatches(var home_score: Long,
                   var away_score: Long,
                   @ColumnInfo(name = "usermatches_id") var id: String,
                   var userchanged: Boolean,
                   var winner: Long) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var num_id: Long = 0
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -usermatches: <---- This is an array

Is not! It's true that if an object is stored in the database as an `array`, `entry.value` returns an ArrayList and not an array, but in your case, `usermatches` is a `map` which in terms contains other maps, `0`, `1` and so on. That's why you also get that error. So in order to solve this, you need to iterate over `usermatches` map twice, once to get the maps and second to get the values whithin those maps.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alex Mamo pointed out, it was indeed a HashMap

What I was doing in the above code snipet was close to how I actually solved the problem.

I was initializing my **Object** inside the third for loop and was making it hold imprecise information from the Firestore DB.

**Solution:**

```
docRef = db.collection("userdata").document(user.user_id)
                docRef.get()
                        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                            if (task.isSuccessful) {

                                val document: DocumentSnapshot = task.result

                                val cedula = document.data!!["cedula"] as Long

                                val points = document.data!!["points"] as Long

                                val alias = document.data!!["username"] as String

                                val map: MutableMap<String, Any>? = document.data
                                for (entry in map!!.entries) {
                                    if (entry.key == "usermatches") {

                                        val list = entry.value as ArrayList<Any>

                                        var home_score: Long = 0
                                        var winner: Long = 0
                                        var userchanged: Boolean = true
                                        var id: String = ""
                                        var away_score: Long = 0

                                        for (each in list){

                                            val usermatch = Usermatches(home_score, away_score, id, userchanged, winner)

                                            for (entry2 in  each as HashMap<String, Any>){

                                                when {
                                                    entry2.key == "away_score" -> usermatch.away_score = entry2.value as Long
                                                    entry2.key == "home_score" -> usermatch.home_score = entry2.value as Long
                                                    entry2.key == "id" -> usermatch.id = entry2.value as String
                                                    entry2.key == "userchanged" -> usermatch.userchanged = entry2.value as Boolean
                                                    entry2.key == "winner" -> usermatch.winner = entry2.value as Long
                                                }

                                            }

                                            println("$usermatch")
                                            mDisposable.add(usermatchesViewModel.insert(usermatch)
                                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                                    .subscribe{println("Checking")})
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting Usermatches ", task.exception)
                            }
                        }
            })
```